# Bash script together with expect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I do have a script which copies files from one box to another.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


spawn scp "user@host:/opt/xxx/201409080500.tar.bz2" /tmp/dantmp
expect {....
     -re ".*es.*no.*"
     {
         exp_send "yes\r"
         exp_continue
     }
     -re ".*sword.*"
     {
         exp_send "Pa55word\r"
     }
 }
interact
```

Script does a job, but unfortunatelly I am not allowed to use any default bash commands inside. For example like `echo` etc, I assume reason is that I haven't imported `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. But if I do import it or use `bash` together with `expect` script is not working at all.

Could you please help me to structure it so I can use both cmd from `bash` as well as `expected`? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you realise that `#!` does not "import" anything? Rather, it calls `expect -f` with your script as a parameter. The script you have written is not a bash script. You should be able to use `expect <<EOF` multiline string syntax in a real bash script to run expect with a script.

Comment: Don't use expect for this. Use ssh keys.