# issue in expect code on Linux server

Tags: linux, shell, unix, expect

I am trying to ssh server using the below script

```
exp_internal 1

    #!/usr/bin/expect

    grep "$1" serverlist.txt
    if [ $? = 0 ]
            then
            eval spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no ghayat@$server_ip
            expect "password: "
            send "Password\r"
            expect "$ "
            send "touch Deepo22_9\r"
            expect "$ "
            send "exit\r"
    interact
    fi
```

but I received the below errors:

```
[root@Server_name DMSSH]# ./testscript.sh $server_ip
./testscript.sh: line 1: exp_internal: command not found
172.24.194.50
./testscript.sh: line 8: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "password: ": no such file or directory
./testscript.sh: line 10: send: command not found
couldn't read file "$ ": no such file or directory
./testscript.sh: line 12: send: command not found
couldn't read file "$ ": no such file or directory
./testscript.sh: line 14: send: command not found
./testscript.sh: line 15: interact: command not found
```

The code is correct without grep & if, So How can I add grep& if corrctly ?

Also I am trying to pass server ip while executing script "$1" to check in DB.txt file first before running ssh, but it seems not working as well.

Comment: This could, in some ways, be considered a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975105/bash-script-together-with-expect

Comment: The problem is that this *isn't* expect code. Expect is based on TCL, not on shell, and TCL syntax needs to be used for flow control constructs and such.

Comment: So Do we've any way to mix sheel & Expect ?

Comment: OR at least calling expect script from shell script, I wanna do script with logic

Comment: @user212051, TCL is a full-featured language -- it has plenty of support for flow control logic; you just need to learn and use its syntax.

Comment: So it's done by invoking expect script from shell script and putting the appropriate format for server IP which suits expect scripts.    THANKS all , Answer goes to me :D

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `grep` and `if` inside an expect script. Those are external commands and shell constructs.

`expect` has its own `if` support if you want to use that (as `expect` is just `tcl`).

But if you want to do other things before calling your expect script you need a wrapper shell script for that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to say

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
exp_internal 1
set server_ip [lindex $argv 0]
if {[catch {grep -q $server_id serverlist.txt} output] == 0} {
    spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no ghayat@$server_ip
    expect "password: "
    send "Password\r"
    expect "$ "
    send "touch Deepo22_9\r"
    expect "$ "
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
}
```